# Binary search complexity

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

In sorted array of numbers binary search gives us comlexity of O(logN).
How will the complexity change if we split array into 3 parts instead of 2 during search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same. You will get a running time only differing by constant factor ($\log_2 3=\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 2}$).

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: If you know how to prove it for binary search, you can easily write down the recurrence relation (it's basically the same idea, except that the size of the subinstance is not longer n/2).
See also [Ternary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search) on Wikipedia (or in any Algorithms book, I reckon).

Comment: Not exactly. The ternary search takes two comparisons per interval, at worse, so $2\log_3N=2\ln N/\ln3$ in total, vs. $\log_2N=\ln N/\ln2$. The ratio is about $\ln4/\ln3$, in favor of the binary search.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the master theorem directly using:

$$
T(n) = T\left( \frac{n}{3} \right) + O(1)
$$

But you can also think intuitively reasoning that if you search on a portion of the array that is 1/3 every time, and you finish when the array portion is of length 1 you need $k$ steps to complete the algorithm, with $k$ computed as:

$$
\frac{n}{3^k} = 1
$$

Therefore $k = log_3 n$, and $O(\log_3 n)$ is the complexity of the algorithm.

The [ternary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search) suggested by Clement C. solves a slightly different problem, where you actually search for a maximum or minimum and not for a specific, given, item. In that case your recursion goes on 2/3 of the array instead of 1/3. I remains true, in any case, that the result is different only by a multiplicative constant, because you can always [change the base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base).